# Aliasing an npm package, without an alias

Tags: npm, webpack, sass

We recently had to switch from `node-sass` to `sass`, because a member of our team using an M1 was suddenly unable to load our React app.

So I switched from:

```
"node-sass": "^4.14.1",
```

to:

```
"node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.49.9"
```

which worked. This was 3+ weeks ago, but today that alias isn't working. Looks like our deployment instance is running NPM 6.4.1 and aliases aren't supported in that version. (Again, everything was working fine until yesterday. I think the instance had been restarted but if that's the problem then this was a ticking time bomb already.)

Our app uses Node 10.15.3 and it's too much of a hassle to just quickly upgrade that. We tried upgrading NPM on the instance but it said NPM doesn't support 10.15.3.

It seems like the quick solution is to not use the alias. So I replaced the line with just `sass@^1.49.9` and now of course I'm getting the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-sass'
src/browser/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/browser/index.css)
```

`node-sass` is nowhere in my code that I could change it to `sass`. How do I fix this?

`webpack.development.js`

```js
const sassLoad = {
  test: /\.s?(a|c)ss$/,
  use: [
    mode.includes("dev") ? "style-loader" : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
    },
    {
      loader: "sass-loader",
    },
  ],
};
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
    rules: [
      linter,
      { oneOf: [imgLoad, jsLoad, sassLoad, fileLoad] },
    ],
  },
```

How do I make the switch? Where do I tell Webpack (or sass-loader or whatever) to look for the right package?

Comment: Why did you pretend that sass _was_ node-sass, instead of just replacing it? Also note Node 10 is out of support (and Node 12 only has a month left).

Comment: I pretended that sass was node-sass for exactly the reason I'm posting this. I don't know how to replace it! (I guess the better question is, how to replace it?)

Comment: Uninstall node-sass, install sass. Sass-loader picks whichever is available.

Comment: (Since [7.2](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#720-2019-08-08), I should say, plus sass-embedded since [12.5](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1250-2022-02-14).)

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work. In fact, now I've reset all my changes back to what they were before all this (back to `"node-sass": "npm:sass@^1.49.9",`) and I still get the same error, meaning my app is completely broken.

Comment: Update on that last comment: it somehow fixed itself, so I tried `npm remove node-sass && npm i -D sass` and I'm back to the same error